# ValueError: [u'path'] while installing mitmproxy

Tags: python, python-2.7, mitmproxy

Getting long msvc9 compiler errors when trying to install mitmproxy with pip. I've so far reinstalled every MSVC version on my computer with the required 64x version, with no luck at all. I've been trying to solve this on my own for over 2 days now, does anyone else have any ideas?

[Here's the full log output](http://pastebin.com/kirQh5JS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mitmproxy author here. In it current state, mitmproxy is not supported on Windows. We'll hopefully release something later this year.

Comment: I appreciate the response, yeah I came to that conclusion after some time. I ended up running ubuntu, after which installation went smoothly.